# Facebook Instant Games Not Giving Player Photo

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-instant-games

I am using this code for getting player photo but response always standard photo url like this: https://platform-lookaside.fbsbx.com/platform/instantgames/profile_pic.jpg?igpid=2740003129452224&height=256&width=256&ext=1585811827&hash=AeSTzH9PG8LqK8se

What is the problem with this coding?

```
window.onload = function() {

FBInstant.initializeAsync().then(function() {

    FBInstant.startGameAsync().then(function() {

        FBInstant.player.getSignedPlayerInfoAsync().then(function (result) {

            console.log(FBInstant.player.getPhoto());

        });

    });

});
```

}

Comment: Did the `getSignedPlayerInfoAsync` call itself return a proper result as you would expect?

Comment: yes, the result as expected.

Comment: I'm seeing this one too, did Facebook make some changes on their end for this API ?